# What exactly happened to Harry Potter's magical family that they could not keep or support him?

Tags: harry-potter, continuity

Story wise and in terms of character, it's understood why Harry Potter, the protagonist of the titular series, is an orphan raised with his muggle (non-magical human) family. However, a recent question I asked here brought to light that not only is Harry a descendant of one of the legendary Peverell brothers, but that the Potters are a family with an extensive line, largely located around Godric's Hallow. An excerpt explains thus:

> Henry’s son was called Fleamont Potter. ... It was Fleamont who took the family gold and quadrupled it, by creating magical Sleekeazy’s Hair Potion (‘two drops tames even the most bothersome barnet’). He sold the company at a vast profit when he retired, but no amount of riches could compensate him or his wife Euphemia for their childlessness. They had quite given up hope of a son or daughter when, to their shock and surprise, Euphemia found that she was pregnant and their beloved boy, James, was born.

> Fleamont and Euphemia lived long enough to see James marry a Muggle-born girl called Lily Evans, but not to meet their grandson, Harry. Dragon pox carried them off within days of each other, due to their advanced age, and James Potter then inherited Ignotus Peverell’s Invisibility Cloak.

So it's understood that Harry's Paternal Grandparents died prior to his birth, but "Several generations" existed prior to them. It would be logical that James would have known *his* grandparents, and thus also some cousins or extended family. This is likely also because in the *Fantastic Beasts* sister series, it is shown that Wizarding families tend to know each other, and stick together, much like the Weasley's and even the Blacks did.

This raises 3 questions:

1. Plot reasons aside, why is the *no mention* of any Second Cousins, Great Aunts or Uncles or other family related to James who may have been able to take Harry, or at least check on him?
2. Considering Harry's fame as "the boy who lived" from the very first book, and James being a good wizard of some regard, why were more precautions *not* taken (on an official level, say by the Ministry of Magic) to protect the child after his parents deaths?
3. Did or does Harry ever learn of his family's link to the Peverells, or are they (as a clan) no longer in existence?

Is there any canon information which addresses any of these issues?

**NOTE:** I am aware that the story is structured as it is to give Harry a "heroes journey", and thus many of these obstacles sort of "had" to be in place.

What I'm more asking here if there was ever any attempt to address these issues in story, i.e.  a mention that all extended Potter clan was killed by Voldemort or hunted by Death Eaters, or that the existing Peverells simply "didn't know" of their family ties to the Potters after several generations lost touch. It could just be that these are minor details that JK Rowling didn't touch upon, but considering her usual attention to detail in universe building, I'm open to a possible "Throw away" explanation being given.